# Python references and mutability

Tags: python, reference, immutability

I'm trying to understand references and mutability. In the code below, why do the copies not get updated for objects and ints, while they do for lists? I thought that when we assign a name to an existing variable, we just add another way to reference the same value, but it seems for objects and ints a new variable is created?

```
import turtle

# Objects
v = turtle.Vec2D(0, 0)
print("v: ", v)
w = v
v += turtle.Vec2D(10, -5)
print("v: ", v)
print("w: ", w)

# Integers
p = 10
print("p: ", p)
q = p
p += 5
print("p: ", p)
print("q: ", q)

# Lists
m = [5, 7]
print("m: ", m)
n = m
m.append(3)
print("m: ", m)
print("n: ", n)
```

Comment: `v += turtle.Vec2D` will return a new object whereas `list.append` updates the object in-place

Comment: Because integers *aren't* mutable, so sharing a reference doesn't matter. Whether the class instance is mutable is a matter of its implementation.